# PostgreSQL 9.1, how to restore a Hot Standby Slave w/o any Wal Files?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a PostgreSQL 9.1 hot standby slave that had all of its wal files removed. How can I restart the standby server and have the slave resync from the master? Thanks

Comment: I'm sure someone will be along with a full answer, but in brief you'll need to take a new base-backup if you've not got the WAL files required.

Answer (score 4):

If the WAL files don't exist anymore anywhere, you need to rebuild the standby from scratch (new base backup).  If you still have the WAL files on the master or in an archive somewhere, just change the `restore_command` in `recovery.conf` to fetch them from wherever they are.